# use of vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector

When should we use vectors and when to use normal arrays. Also in one of my codes i found a weird problem.

```
 class TwoTrains   
   {  
          public:  
          int pass(int t1, int t2, vector <int>);  
   };

int TwoTrains::pass(int t1, int t2, vector <int> times)  
     {  
         int size_of_array=(int)times.size();  
         for(int i=0;i<size_of_array;i++)  
         {  
              cout<<times[i]<<endl;  
         }  
         return 0;  
     }
```

This Compiles but when i use this it gives an error.Why -

```
 for(int i=0; i< times.size();i++)
```

Comment: 99% of the time you'll probably want a vector.

Comment: What's the point of casting an `int` to an `int`? That's pointless.

Comment: @Linuxios, IIRC, `std::vector<int>::size_type` is an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I meant that. Are they not the same, though, minus one obviously asking to be used to hold sizes?

Comment: There are two questions here.. please decide which you want answered.

Comment: @chris I think so, just being pedantic :P

Comment: @chris: I know. Which makes it almost as pointless to cast to int. Possibly dangerous.

Comment: @chris : Typically `size_t` is `unsigned` on x86 and `unsigned long long` on x64.

Comment: Is your compile error a `-Werror` from comparing signed and unsigned integers?

Comment: Following the long discussion, in any case you shouldn't use an `int` here, and should use `vector<int>::size_type`. And you should also use an iterator rather than indexes.

Comment: So you found a weird problem, but you don't give any hint what that problem is? Don't you think it would be useful to tell us what problem you are seeing?

Comment: @ildjarn: Interesting. Wonder why it's so much larger on x86-64 (going from probably 32 bits to most likely 128 or 256 bits -- that's *massive*). `long long` is usually 2x long, which is often 2x int. On 64 bit, that makes `long long` (in that situation) 64  * 2 * 2 = 256. That's 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936 posible values. Before you get to that many elements, your probably out of memory.

Comment: @chris and @Luchian: To be more pedantic, `size_t` is not necessarily the same as `unsigned int` - it might be a larger type (ie., `size_t` might be 64-bits while `unsigned int` is 32-bits).  Also, even more pedantically, `std::vector<>::size()` returns the type `std::vector<>::size_type`. I'm don't know if there's any good reason why the standard didn't just use `size_t`.

Comment: @Linuxios : `std::uint64_t` if you prefer, but `long` is 32-bits on all x64 platforms I'm aware of (and `long long` is 64-bits).

Comment: @ildjarn: `uint64_t` is equivalent to `unsigned long long` on x86-64? I find that hard to believe. That would mean that `int`, `long`, and `long long` are all the same size. That seems unrealistic.

Comment: @ildjarn: `size_t` is implementation defined per C99 specification. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: @ildjarn: Sorry, saw edit to comment. Really? Than what's `int`? I'd think it would be native DWORD, or 64 bits on x86-64.

Comment: @0A0D: Exactly, but you can still often find that it is the platform's `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Linuxios: Well, more accurately it depends on what is in stddef.h

Comment: @Linuxios: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models for a description of the various 64-bit data models and what systems use them.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Interesting, thanks. That makes sense for backward compatibility for C programs that use bit shifts that assume the size of `int`s to be 32 bit (although they should be using `sizeof`).

Comment: @Linuxios: It will be an `unsigned integer`, that much is certain. `unsigned int`, maybe not.

Comment: @Linuxios: I'm not sure how much importance bit shifting operations were in deciding which 64-bit data model to use. I think APIs, data structures and how often code would stash pointers in integer data types were more important considerations.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/31/363790.aspx for some discussion on why MS opted for LLP64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector` is what you want. Give arrays for plain-C users.

```
for(int i=0; i< times.size();i++)
```

Gives no errors, but warning (Comparing `signed` with `unsigned` ). Use

```
for(size_t i=0; i< times.size();i++)
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i<(int) times.size();i++)
```

As you don't need indexes, use iterators, as [0A0D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195488/0a0d) notice:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = times.begin(); it!=times.end();++it){
    cout<<*it;
}
```

or even

```
for(int t: times){
    cout<<t;
}
```

with C++11

Comment: I feel bad for saying this, but as a good habit, `const_iterator` for just printing.